# ember-cli is hanging on ember server command

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I just followed the 'getting started' post on ember-cli's homepage.

I installed ember 0.1.2, bower, phantomjs, etc.

I created my app, however, when I run 'ember server' it outputs the following:

```
version: 0.1.2
Livereload server on port 35729
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200
```

But freezes.  When i try to access the page it hangs indefinitely.  I also cant close the server (ctrl+c).  I am forced to kill -9.

I would really like to get this worked out if possible!  I had an earlier version of ember-cli installed ( 0.0.3 ish? )  and it was working fine at the time.

If more information is required, please let me know what you need in the comments!

ember -v outputs :

```
version: 0.1.2
node: 0.13.0-pre
npm: 2.1.2
```

Thanks

Comment: No errors no nothing?

Comment: `ember -v` output could be useful. Also, windows, linux, mac?

Comment: I added ember -v output to the question.  Im on mac the latest yosemite (10.10).  I don't see any errors, and am not sure how to debug hanging like this.

Comment: Have you tried running with a non-pre version of node?

Comment: Try `ember build`, sometimes `ember serve` does not report errors propertly.

Comment: i ended up installing nvm to manage node version, set default v to the latest stable version and it worked! Thanks for the help - feel free to create the answer, i'll accept afterwards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a bug in the upgrade process from watchman 4.6 to 4.7. The solution, [from the watchman team](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6259#issuecomment-247110522) (which doesn't require you to uninstall and reinstall watchman) is to reload the watchman launch daemon. Once you do, it'll spin itself back up correctly:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist
watchman version
```

This should output something like this:

```
/Users/<user>/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist: Could not find specified service
{
    "version": "4.7.0"
}
```

If for some reason that *doesn't* work, you can fall back to another workaround (which also doesn't require uninstalling and reinstalling watchman): delete the existing watchman socket from your "state", where `<user>` below is your username (e.g. for me it's `chris`, so `chris-state` instead of `<user>-state`). For example, if you used Homebrew to install, that command looks like this:

```
rm /usr/local/var/run/watchman/<user>-state/sock
```

The problem here arises from a Watchman upgrade which failed to properly clear out all the relevant data. You can see where they tracked down the underlying cause [here](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/358), and the original Ember issue [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6259).

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue today, and found that it is a watchman issue.

If you run `watchman version` (like ember-cli does), it hangs, and re-installing watchman solves the issue

By the way, you can see the ember-cli's output by setting the DEBUG environment variable, like this: `DEBUG=* ember build`. In my case it shows "ember-cli:watcher detecting watchman" as the last message when its hangs.

https://github.com/twitter/libwatchman/issues/5

https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/96

Comment: Note: per the other answer, you do *not* need to uninstall and reinstall watchman. That will work, but it's a lot of unnecessary time. :)

Comment: If you're using watchman@4.7.0:
```I solved it by deleting the <PREFIX>/var/run/watchman/<USER>-state folder (If you installed it with Homebrew, it should be /usr/local/var/run/watchman/).```

Comment: `brew uninstall watchman --force && brew install watchman` fixed this for me